# Getting the Bound Field Name at Run Time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding

If I have a control, within a FormView, that is bound using a `<% #Bind(...)%>` expression.  At run time, is there any way of retrieving the name of the field the control is bound to.

To be clear, if the expression is `<% #Bind("UserName") %>`

I want to return the string `"UserName"`.

Answer (score 1):

after messing around extensively in debug, I found this to work

```
((System.Web.UI.WebControls.AutoGeneratedField)((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(e.Row.Cells[0])).ContainingField).SortExpression
```

In debug use shift+F9 to open the quick watch window pain and explore your Event Argument visually